# How to verify that http://nodeosd:8888 is valid?

Tags: nodeos, docker

I am trying to run the following -

```
cleos get transaction c96905dee9a9652c8190f2d2bd5221bb0ac65a06b4381451107221c1076c91a8
```

I get this -

```
Error 3200006: invalid http request
Error Details:
The server has rejected the request as invalid!
Please verify this url is valid: http://nodeosd:8888/v1/history/get_transaction
If the condition persists, please contact the RPC server administrator for nodeosd!
```

Has anyone any idea the cause of this error?

I have this running for nodeos -

```
[
    {
        "Id": "fd96eb220dc3e20fe8b3779caea38a1653814b97ad16083520bf26d40580586a",
        "Created": "2018-08-09T14:15:09.544844011Z",
        "Path": "/opt/eosio/bin/nodeosd.sh",
        "Args": [
            "--data-dir",
            "/opt/eosio/bin/data-dir",
            "-e",
            "--http-alias=nodeosd:8888",
            "--http-alias=127.0.0.1:8888",
            "--http-alias=localhost:8888",
            "--plugin",
            "eosio::chain_plugin",
            "--plugin",
            "eosio::mongo_db_plugin",
            "--plugin",
            "eosio::history_plugin",
            "--plugin",
            "eosio::chain_plugin",
            "--plugin",
            "eosio::http_plugin"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 15464,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-08-09T14:15:11.902978386Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:95dcdb9913215add708cccb029512043fc0b3189c0fd8ae7cb234ccdf276524b",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/fd96eb220dc3e20fe8b3779caea38a1653814b97ad16083520bf26d40580586a/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/fd96eb220dc3e20fe8b3779caea38a1653814b97ad16083520bf26d40580586a/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/fd96eb220dc3e20fe8b3779caea38a1653814b97ad16083520bf26d40580586a/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/fd96eb220dc3e20fe8b3779caea38a1653814b97ad16083520bf26d40580586a/fd96eb220dc3e20fe8b3779caea38a1653814b97ad16083520bf26d40580586a-json.log",
        "Name": "/docker_nodeosd_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "nodeos-data-volume:/opt/eosio/bin/data-dir:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "docker_default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8888/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8888"
                    }
                ],
                "9876/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "9876"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": [
                "IPC_LOCK"
            ],
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/720a47b3a232c1b7b80044b98eaadd98857352521f0da1b7706018752614cc80-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/08756bc37baa342605e9df49f9b90b2555f0a657ae722bc7bc866918125f4a9e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/92713c491bf25a3241f2d5ce24a8465b0f866dcf56fcd22ca9c3e28604114279/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7965b27ddbe6ae92ce844db22f7f12f4de9203bd3d8417ebd6504694b99d2b65/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2534f13c54c92ee323d42c052aa78454b85a760c29fc52852af49c751501a308/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/96245b036da6cb26f8f43e4c76c6a085ebe90943793b9a2d889165a019b785be/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/587bfb1b52896de23f29c0aa8f3dbae479dc37af7dcc82b9ccad072362ed538e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/568dd6d82425cfb991576c26e69def0c7012ba1f9cdd49dc65b68f7a28bbadf7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6adaee7f6b31a99d34df78cface72bb31ef9f18580ff599f0bea6d23b1cbc3dc/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dadfe0a81d5fa3d98befb45dc39151890798f03c9b9f6e69fe49cb5eaa9d461a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dcc20e266049fecf3dcd7ced11ebbab77ab941f5c2ed31ffc923008a722191f9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1c4e6d4f4f7798084b53d63035821883a085894191b36f48421cdaeb6c9c0d30/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3d8a16d4188748027224a8e23ebd96392a778e93f19040b77143dc8be7a3562e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f8363fdb756dbc6cf1b24db682af914ab17ec00f30b041b33b91a7a6f554e0ee/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/720a47b3a232c1b7b80044b98eaadd98857352521f0da1b7706018752614cc80/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/720a47b3a232c1b7b80044b98eaadd98857352521f0da1b7706018752614cc80/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/720a47b3a232c1b7b80044b98eaadd98857352521f0da1b7706018752614cc80/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "nodeos-data-volume",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/nodeos-data-volume/_data",
                "Destination": "/opt/eosio/bin/data-dir",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "nodeosd",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8888/tcp": {},
                "9876/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/opt/eosio/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "EOSIO_ROOT=/opt/eosio",
                "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/opt/eosio/bin/nodeosd.sh",
                "--data-dir",
                "/opt/eosio/bin/data-dir",
                "-e",
                "--http-alias=nodeosd:8888",
                "--http-alias=127.0.0.1:8888",
                "--http-alias=localhost:8888",
                "--plugin",
                "eosio::chain_plugin",
                "--plugin",
                "eosio::mongo_db_plugin",
                "--plugin",
                "eosio::history_plugin",
                "--plugin",
                "eosio::chain_plugin",
                "--plugin",
                "eosio::http_plugin"
            ],
            "Image": "eosio/eos",
            "Volumes": {
                "/opt/eosio/bin/data-dir": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "8caf49a32c6cd30cdd2707f677b5fe06bec425e38403e452ad5c254523940b32",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "docker",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "nodeosd",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.22.0"
            },
            "StopTimeout": 600
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "398995b0b022fe7740981f01225a2453677cb2f80104b8ce78277c017ed3b56c",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8888/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8888"
                    }
                ],
                "9876/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "9876"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/398995b0b022",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "docker_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "nodeosd",
                        "fd96eb220dc3"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "1479ad6db41291d3358a6cce3ee38051a9fd783e11dfe0cf78fbdfdfd6b9844a",
                    "EndpointID": "c3366eb5c63e7da4ae14bcf3609f83577922e1202c04268b2cade338ab829877",
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.23.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

My docker containers -

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES 
6515319af10a        eosio/eos           "/opt/eosio/bin/keos…"   30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes                                      docker_keosd_1 
fd96eb220dc3        eosio/eos           "/opt/eosio/bin/node…"   30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes      0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9876-9876/tcp   docker_nodeosd_1
```

I add -p in the nodeos part and now I get this -

```
cleos get transaction c96905dee9a9652c8190f2d2bd5221bb0ac65a06b4381451107221c1076c91a8
Error 3200004: fail to resolve host
Error Details:
Error resolving "nodeosd:${url}" : Host not found (non-authoritative), try again later
```

Comment: Can you try to set  http-validate-host = false  in your config.ini ?

Comment: I tried - no difference. cleos get block works so the chain is running.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the --filter-on switch against the account/action you want to capture when running `nodeos`

E.g.

`--filter-on ${Contract}:${Action}`

`--filter-on karmaaccount:createpost:`

Full example

```
nodeos -e -p eosio -d /mnt/dev/data --config-dir /mnt/dev/config --http-validate-host=false --plugin eosio::wallet_api_plugin --plugin eosio::wallet_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin --filter-on karmaaccount:createpost: --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 --access-control-allow-origin=* --contracts-console &
```

From `nodeos --help`

```
Config Options for eosio::history_plugin:
  -f [ --filter-on ] arg                Track actions which match 
                                        receiver:action:actor. Actor may be 
                                        blank to include all. Receiver and 
                                        Action may not be blank.
```

Official documentation for the API endpoint can be found on the [Developers Portal](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_transaction-1) however the payload structure is wrong as forces `id` to be an Integer when it should be a string.

A successful payload looks like this

```
{
    "id": "f73636bf702ef0129f500bcfe654329c48c0903888e0b7dc01296dec91c41cc9"
}
```

With a response like this.

```
{
    "id": "f73636bf702ef0129f500bcfe654329c48c0903888e0b7dc01296dec91c41cc9",
    "trx": {
        "receipt": {
            "status": "executed",
            "cpu_usage_us": 866,
            "net_usage_words": 42,
            "trx": [
                1,
                {
                    "signatures": [
                        "SIG_K1_KXQLRQgmib7cYqD9QkZUjoZbCBuxhzQxfGnVpTXLMfj6QqReeSb8WERsoviEZNfZqW8xzRph8zGGRs3N9MuR5bKaZSwVP2"
                    ],
                    "compression": "none",
                    "packed_context_free_data": "",
                    "packed_trx": "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"
                }
            ]
        },
        "trx": {
            "expiration": "2018-08-25T00:37:53",
            "ref_block_num": 48,
            "ref_block_prefix": 185920952,
            "max_net_usage_words": 0,
            "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
            "delay_sec": 0,
            "context_free_actions": [],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "account": "karmaaccount",
                    "name": "createpost",
                    "authorization": [
                        {
                            "actor": "sarabrown",
                            "permission": "active"
                        }
                    ],
                    "data": {
                        "post": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "author": "sarabrown",
                            "description": "Let's get wild today. You can work lots of happy things in here. A fan brush is a fantastic piece of equipment. Automatically, beautiful things happen.",
                            "lat": "a",
                            "lng": "b",
                            "imagehashes": [
                                "QmT4AeWE9Q9EaoyLJiqaZuYQ8mJeq4ZBncjjFH9dQ9uDVA"
                            ],
                            "videohashes": [
                                "hash"
                            ],
                            "categories": [
                                1
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "hex_data": "01000000000000000000989cde63aec197014c65742773206765742077696c6420746f6461792e20596f752063616e20776f726b206c6f7473206f66206861707079207468696e677320696e20686572652e20412066616e20627275736820697320612066616e746173746963207069656365206f662065717569706d656e742e204175746f6d61746963616c6c792c2062656175746966756c207468696e67732068617070656e2e01610162012e516d54344165574539513945616f794c4a6971615a755951386d4a6571345a426e636a6a46483964513975445641010468617368010100000000000000"
                }
            ],
            "transaction_extensions": [],
            "signatures": [
                "SIG_K1_KXQLRQgmib7cYqD9QkZUjoZbCBuxhzQxfGnVpTXLMfj6QqReeSb8WERsoviEZNfZqW8xzRph8zGGRs3N9MuR5bKaZSwVP2"
            ],
            "context_free_data": []
        }
    },
    "block_time": "2018-08-25T00:37:23.500",
    "block_num": 50,
    "last_irreversible_block": 2496,
    "traces": [
        {
            "receipt": {
                "receiver": "karmaaccount",
                "act_digest": "5cf91290925b22530ced63ab3bcc1639ed24ff3b32b3cbcc3769f153f18acf06",
                "global_sequence": 69,
                "recv_sequence": 11,
                "auth_sequence": [
                    [
                        "sarabrown",
                        1
                    ]
                ],
                "code_sequence": 1,
                "abi_sequence": 1
            },
            "act": {
                "account": "karmaaccount",
                "name": "createpost",
                "authorization": [
                    {
                        "actor": "sarabrown",
                        "permission": "active"
                    }
                ],
                "data": {
                    "post": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "author": "sarabrown",
                        "description": "Let's get wild today. You can work lots of happy things in here. A fan brush is a fantastic piece of equipment. Automatically, beautiful things happen.",
                        "lat": "a",
                        "lng": "b",
                        "imagehashes": [
                            "QmT4AeWE9Q9EaoyLJiqaZuYQ8mJeq4ZBncjjFH9dQ9uDVA"
                        ],
                        "videohashes": [
                            "hash"
                        ],
                        "categories": [
                            1
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "hex_data": "01000000000000000000989cde63aec197014c65742773206765742077696c6420746f6461792e20596f752063616e20776f726b206c6f7473206f66206861707079207468696e677320696e20686572652e20412066616e20627275736820697320612066616e746173746963207069656365206f662065717569706d656e742e204175746f6d61746963616c6c792c2062656175746966756c207468696e67732068617070656e2e01610162012e516d54344165574539513945616f794c4a6971615a755951386d4a6571345a426e636a6a46483964513975445641010468617368010100000000000000"
            },
            "elapsed": 651,
            "cpu_usage": 0,
            "console": "",
            "total_cpu_usage": 0,
            "trx_id": "f73636bf702ef0129f500bcfe654329c48c0903888e0b7dc01296dec91c41cc9",
            "inline_traces": [
                {
                    "receipt": {
                        "receiver": "karmaaccount",
                        "act_digest": "46a45a3eecb3b293150fc3b09c696df9e5dd8b3f9fca24c6756349c02b151836",
                        "global_sequence": 70,
                        "recv_sequence": 12,
                        "auth_sequence": [
                            [
                                "karmaaccount",
                                9
                            ]
                        ],
                        "code_sequence": 1,
                        "abi_sequence": 1
                    },
                    "act": {
                        "account": "karmaaccount",
                        "name": "postid",
                        "authorization": [
                            {
                                "actor": "karmaaccount",
                                "permission": "active"
                            }
                        ],
                        "data": {
                            "id": 5
                        },
                        "hex_data": "0500000000000000"
                    },
                    "elapsed": 25,
                    "cpu_usage": 0,
                    "console": "",
                    "total_cpu_usage": 0,
                    "trx_id": "f73636bf702ef0129f500bcfe654329c48c0903888e0b7dc01296dec91c41cc9",
                    "inline_traces": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```